# How to use Task.run to perform the function of Do_Work() of a background worker

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library, backgroundworker

I move 4 objects in parallel in a specific paths stored in a list of paths, when each of them complete one path(specific coordinates) it switches to another!.

I used 4 background workers to perform such a job in background and in each call each background worker should try 6 paths (chromosomes) extracted from an a text file and each path stored in different 6 lists and each list contains the coordinates for each path. The coordinates then converted to 2D points to perform projection and each path at a specific depth as the paths to move these objects on different layers using a projection technique i.e. ach object (worker) will be moved at different layer.

Each worker should move the object forward and backward using one path (chromosome) then switches to the next and it should finish the first attempt (path) completely before switch to next in order to calculate the time consumed and other factors such as "Fitness" function.

The following is an example on one  the Do_Work() methods:

```
    private void auv0Genetic_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {

        List<PointF> genetic2DLayerPath1 = new List<PointF>(); //  from chromosome 1
        List<PointF> genetic2DLayerPath2 = new List<PointF>(); //  from chromosome 2
        List<PointF> genetic2DLayerPath3 = new List<PointF>(); //  from chromosome 3
        List<PointF> genetic2DLayerPath4 = new List<PointF>(); //  from chromosome 4
        List<PointF> genetic2DLayerPath5 = new List<PointF>(); //  from chromosome 5
        List<PointF> genetic2DLayerPath6 = new List<PointF>(); //  from chromosome 6

        countNumOfPaths_auv_1 = 0;

        float[] xPoints = new float[1];
        float[] yPoints = new float[1]; 

        foreach (int[,] arr in pathChromosom1)
        {
            Point3D pointIn3D = new Point3D(cellsCenters[0, arr[0, 0]], cellsCenters[1, arr[1, 0]], 700);
            PointF pointIn2D = Project(pointIn3D); // convert to 2D
            genetic2DLayerPath1.Add(pointIn2D);
        }

        foreach (int[,] arr in pathChromosom2)
        {
            Point3D pointIn3D = new Point3D(cellsCenters[0, arr[0, 0]], cellsCenters[1, arr[1, 0]], 700);
            PointF pointIn2D = Project(pointIn3D); // convert to 2D
            genetic2DLayerPath2.Add(pointIn2D);
        }

        foreach (int[,] arr in pathChromosom3)
        {
            Point3D pointIn3D = new Point3D(cellsCenters[0, arr[0, 0]], cellsCenters[1, arr[1, 0]], 700);
            PointF pointIn2D = Project(pointIn3D); // convert to 2D
            genetic2DLayerPath3.Add(pointIn2D);
        }


        foreach (int[,] arr in pathChromosom4)
        {
            Point3D pointIn3D = new Point3D(cellsCenters[0, arr[0, 0]], cellsCenters[1, arr[1, 0]], 700);
            PointF pointIn2D = Project(pointIn3D); // convert to 2D
            genetic2DLayerPath4.Add(pointIn2D);
        }

        foreach (int[,] arr in pathChromosom5)
        {
            Point3D pointIn3D = new Point3D(cellsCenters[0, arr[0, 0]], cellsCenters[1, arr[1, 0]], 700);
            PointF pointIn2D = Project(pointIn3D); // convert to 2D
            genetic2DLayerPath5.Add(pointIn2D);
        }

        foreach (int[,] arr in pathChromosom6)
        {
            Point3D pointIn3D = new Point3D(cellsCenters[0, arr[0, 0]], cellsCenters[1, arr[1, 0]], 700);
            PointF pointIn2D = Project(pointIn3D); // convert to 2D
            genetic2DLayerPath6.Add(pointIn2D);
        }

        int counter = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            if (i == 0) // first chromosome
            {
                xPoints = new float[genetic2DLayerPath1.Count()];
                yPoints = new float[genetic2DLayerPath1.Count()];

                auv[0].auvDepth = 700;

                foreach(PointF p in genetic2DLayerPath1)
                {
                    xPoints[counter] = p.X;
                    yPoints[counter] = p.Y;
                    counter++;
                }
                counter = 0;
            }

            if (i == 1) // second chromosome
            {
                xPoints = new float[genetic2DLayerPath2.Count()];
                yPoints = new float[genetic2DLayerPath2.Count()];

                auv[0].auvDepth = 700;

                foreach (PointF p in genetic2DLayerPath2)
                {
                    xPoints[counter] = p.X;
                    yPoints[counter] = p.Y;
                    counter++;
                }
                counter = 0;
            }

            if (i == 2) // third chromosome
            {
                xPoints = new float[genetic2DLayerPath3.Count()];
                yPoints = new float[genetic2DLayerPath3.Count()];

                auv[0].auvDepth = 700;

                foreach (PointF p in genetic2DLayerPath3)
                {
                    xPoints[counter] = p.X;
                    yPoints[counter] = p.Y;
                    counter++;
                }
                counter = 0;
            }

            if (i == 3) // fourth chromosome
            {
                xPoints = new float[genetic2DLayerPath4.Count()];
                yPoints = new float[genetic2DLayerPath4.Count()];

                auv[0].auvDepth = 700;

                foreach (PointF p in genetic2DLayerPath4)
                {
                    xPoints[counter] = p.X;
                    yPoints[counter] = p.Y;
                    counter++;
                }
                counter = 0;
            }

            if (i == 4) // fifth chromosome
            {
                xPoints = new float[genetic2DLayerPath5.Count()];
                yPoints = new float[genetic2DLayerPath5.Count()];

                auv[0].auvDepth = 700;

                foreach (PointF p in genetic2DLayerPath5)
                {
                    xPoints[counter] = p.X;
                    yPoints[counter] = p.Y;
                    counter++;
                }
                counter = 0;
            }

            if (i == 5) // sixth chromosome
            {
                xPoints = new float[genetic2DLayerPath6.Count()];
                yPoints = new float[genetic2DLayerPath6.Count()];

                auv[0].auvDepth = 700;

                foreach (PointF p in genetic2DLayerPath6)
                {
                    xPoints[counter] = p.X;
                    yPoints[counter] = p.Y;
                    counter++;
                }
                counter = 0;
            }

            counter = 0;

                while (countNumOfPaths_auv_1 != 2)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(900); // assume that it represents the speed of the AUV which is in our case = 3 m/s as each meter equal to 300 seconds in thread.sleep()  

                    if (auv0Genetic.CancellationPending)
                    {
                        e.Cancel = true;
                        return;
                    }

                    if (forward)
                    {
                        if (counter == xPoints.Length - 1)
                        {
                            backward = true;
                            forward = false;
                            countNumOfPaths_auv_1++;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            auv[0].auvX = xPoints[counter];
                            auv[0].auvY = yPoints[counter];

                            counter++;
                        }
                    }

                    if (backward)
                    {
                        if (counter == 0)
                        {
                            backward = false;
                            forward = true;
                            countNumOfPaths_auv_1++;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            auv[0].auvX = xPoints[counter];
                            auv[0].auvY = yPoints[counter];
                            counter--;
                        }
                    }

                    //////////////////////// Draw ///////////////////////////
                    iSetupDisplay = 0;

                    if (iSetupDisplay != -1)
                    {
                        iSetupDisplay += 10;
                        if (iSetupDisplay >= topology.Width)
                            iSetupDisplay = -1;
                        topology.Refresh();
                    }
                /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                }
        }

    }
```

I declared each background worker like this:

```
    auv0Genetic = new BackgroundWorker();

                    auv0Genetic.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;

                    auv0Genetic.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(auv0Genetic_DoWork);

                    auv0Genetic.RunWorkerCompleted += new 

RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(auv0Genetic_RunWorkerCompleted);
```

I declared them in a loop that loops 250 times and call them inside this loop each time by calling another method that contains the following lines:

```
auv0Genetic.RunWorkerAsync(geneticIteration); // start AUV # 1
```

**Problems :**

There is no synchronization between the loop and the `Do_Work()` method i.e. the loop starts new iteration before the 4  backgrounds worker finishes their work completely where for each iteration there is a list contains 6 different paths (chromosomes) and each background worker should tries them before the next iteration with the new list. I need to stop the workers completely before going to the next iteration. I put a message box outside the loop and I do not get it appeared after the completion of the loop even after all the workers stop.

**My Question Is:**

I faced some problems with using background workers so I wondered if it is possible to use Task class instead, if so .. then how to use `Task.run`  to perform the same job inside `Do_Work()` methods ?

Comment: So rather than investigate and solve the problems encountered by your first attempt at using a particular multi threading mechanism, you aim to solve the problem by making another first attempt at using a different multi threading mechanism? Isn't that a bit like borrowing money to pay off a loan? Why don't we take a look at some of these backgroundworker problems instead? Simple stuff like "I used 4 background workers to manipulate 4 objects and declared the workers 250 times" - hmm, seems like the start of something problematic..

Comment: "borrowing money to pay off a loan" - can make sense regarding interest rates ... Transferred to question: OP may still have problems, but might go around some of those she has now. Also, if (I know - IF) she is planning on embracing TPL / TAP in her overall architecture, then moving away from BackgroundWorker is reasonable. In the course, there may be enlightenment on what were the problems in the first attempt, too.

Comment: Rose: Just some hints for improvement. Your DoWork method contains *a lot* duplicate code. You may want to reduce that significantly. Then, you seem to be using resources not local to the DoWork method. That means you rely on "side effects" to gather results etc. That has at least some smell to it. To give you decent advice though, we'd have to know *what were the problems you mentioned*.

Comment: You want to execute `auv0Genetic_DoWork` a total of 1000 times - 4 at a time, wait for those to complete, then start the next 4?

Comment: @Rose convert the do work method to one that returns a `Task` you can then group the calls and invoke them together with `Task.WhenAll` for your loops. For the sleep you can use `await Task.Delay(900)`. The content of the methods make no sense to me but I think I get what you are trying to do with TPL....somewhat.

Comment: @Rose for such code (one big method) a BGW is exactly the same as calling `Task.Run(()=>thatBigMethod());`and not waiting for the result. A BGW doesn't make the loops inside the method run in a parallel/concurrent/whatever way. If you want one execution to happen before the other, you can use `await Task.Run(()=FirstCall()); await Task.Run(()=>SecondCall());` etc.

Comment: @Rose that said, this is a *serious* waste of CPU power. Instead of executing iterations one by one in the background, you can rewrite your method in a more efficient way and use either PLINQ or Parallel.ForEach to parallelize the various loops. Right now you only get a non-freezing UI without any speedup. With parallelization you could get 2x-4x times faster execution depending on the number of cores

Comment: @Rose your code looks to simply move values around. If it actually performed any calculations on float values you could use the System.Numeric.Vector class and its methods to use SIMD operations and process 3-4 floats in a single operation, eg add two 3D points in a single operation. This could give you another 4x speedup on top of the parallelization benefit.

Comment: @Rose explain what you actually want to do instead of posting how you tried to do it now. It will be a lot easier to create a fast version of the code if people don't have to reverse-engineer the current code to understand what it's supposed to do. For example, you wouldn't have to check the value of `i` 6 times if, instead of having 6 lists you had a 2D array. Adding elements one by one results in CPU and RAM waste as well. If you already know the dimensions (which you do, through that .Count()` call), you can allocate the 2D array just once.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos :I've updated my question, kindly take a look and note that I use VS 2012

Answer (score 3):

The main concept is:

```
public async Task WorkerStartedMethod()
{
    for(int i = 0; i<=250; i++)
    {
        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
        tasks.add(Task.Run(auv0Genetic_DoWork));
        tasks.add(Task.Run(auv0Genetic_DoWork));
        tasks.add(Task.Run(auv0Genetic_DoWork));
        tasks.add(Task.Run(auv0Genetic_DoWork));
        tasks.add(Task.Run(auv0Genetic_DoWork));
        tasks.add(Task.Run(auv0Genetic_DoWork));
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }
}
```

However I have an assumption that "DoWork" method should be rewritten in case you need access to the UI thread. You should add dispatchers in all parts where you try change something on the UI.

Answer (score 0):

### **My Assumptions to be able to give an answer:**

- This uses objects with associated tasks as you sounded interested in using tasks and yes it will go much smoother than jerryrigging background workers.
- I am going to assume that you understand your business logic and
  there is no need for me to.
- I will focus on a way to process data in a uniform way with options
  to increase capacity.
- Of course I am willing to amend and illuminate unclear areas.
- This should be considered Psuedo Code, I did not compile this and with the missing ideas it would not compile.  Some edits to fix small things may be needed as I was going for the big picture idea here not the details.

### ***THE CODE***

**INCLUDES**

The Includes you will need:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;
```

**PROCESSING LOOP**

This is the main loop you could call this from a single background worker:

```
public void BeginProcess()
{
    //This is the limitation on threads/cpu usage
    var maxWorkers = 4;
    //You could tackle how to go through the loop many ways this was how I was doing it for a simple file transfer program so I didn't change the paradigm
    var currentWorker = 0;

    //This is the Worker List that will hold and then run our chromosome business logic
    var ChromosomeWorkers = new List<ChromWorker>();

    //I am not sure based on the code how you are running through this, but here is a population example
    foreach (var chromTemplate in ChromosomeTemplates)
    {

        var cw = new ChromWorker(/*pass in appropriate arrays etc*/);
        ChromosomeWorkers.Add(cw);


            //If the count of Running workers is less than Max Workers and we are not at the end of the list Continue starting them
        if (ChromosomeWorkers.Count(x => x.Running) < maxWorkers && currentWorker < ChromosomeWorkers.Count)
        {
            ChromosomeWorkers[currentWorker].Start();
            currentWorker++;
        }


    }


    //Transition from Creation to Pure Processing
    do
    {
        if (ChromosomeWorkers.Count(x => x.Running) < maxWorkers && currentWorker < ChromosomeWorkers.Count)
        {
            FilesToBeTransferred[currentWorker].Start();
            currentWorker++;
        }
        else
        {
            //If the workers are maxed then sleep for a bit on this thread
            Thread.Sleep(150);
        }
    }
    while (currentWorker < ChromosomeWorkers.Count);


}
```

**WORKER CLASS**

**NOTE:** There are a lot of other Task states you might have to account for like IsFaulted, etc.  I wanted to keep this concise so I did not go into those cases but you might have to account for them.

This is the worker class which will do most of the footwork:

```
public class ChromWorker
{
    private Task _t;

    bool isConsumed = false;
    pathChromosom1 [,];
    string _Key = string.Empty;
    List<Tag> _Tags = new List<Tag>();

    public ChromWorker(/*Data that might be useful in your worker*/)
    {
        pathChromosom1 = inChromosomeArrays;


    }


    public bool Running
    {
        get
        {

            if (_t == null || _t.IsCompleted ) return false;

            return true;
        }
    }

    public bool Done
    {
        get
        {
            return _t != null && _t.IsCompleted;
        }
    }

    public bool Ready
    {
        get { return _t == null; }
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        _t = new Task(_Run);
        _t.Start();

    }

    private void _Run()
    {
        double tries = 0;
        bool Handled = false;
        while (!Handled && tries < Math.Pow(10, 6))
        {
            //Increase our giveup loop
            tries++;
            try
            {
                /* your Business logic */
                Handled = true;

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0} StackTrace: {1}", e.Message, e.StackTrace);
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I've updated my question, kindly take a look and note that I use VS 2012

Comment: I am not a real expert on 2012 anymore.  Does that mean some of the included libraries I used are not available?

Comment: @Rose do you think if someone has gone to this much trouble you should qualify which components are not available? [VS2012 supports .Net 4.5](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jasonz/2012/08/15/visual-studio-2012-and-net-framework-4-5-released-to-the-web/) and there is nothing in this code .Net 4.5 doesn't support. Please tag your question with VS or .Net version next time to set expectations and avoid disappointment.

Comment: @Carter : could you clarify your answer please... it is not a complete answer , there is some ambiguity!

Comment: I can only imagine you are speaking to the actual work you are doing which we cannot really understand because we don't know the definition of forward or backward and where they are even defined. You will have to bring in some of your globally defined variables and their purpose for me to get close to figuring out your business logic.